# WPF - VirtualPanel / ZoomableCanvas - Fastest way to find the intersection of objects in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am using a WPF controller called ZoomableCanvas (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items.aspx), which is a virtualized canvas (renders only what needs to be in the display area). I am trying to implement a method to, given the viewport rectangle, finds objects in the ObservableCollection whose top/left parameters as a point intersect the rectangle. I've got it working, as below:

```
//This is all in a class that inherits from ObserableCollection<BlockTile> 
//Where blocktile is a struct-like class used to store brush and position info for the 
//tiles that make up our canvas content.

public IEnumerable<int> Query(Rect rectangle)
{
         rectangle.Intersect(Extent); //Extent is our total data set, in case the         
                                      //viewport pans past our data set. 

         foreach (BlockTile t in this)
         {
             if(rectangle.Contains(new Point(t.left, t.top)))
             {
                  yield return (int)this.IndexOf(t);
             }
         }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that my BlockTile collection is around 70,000 items and iterating across the entire data set is killing performance. I'm trying to figure out if, given an IEnumerable of objects, there's a way to filter these items without iterating the entire resultset. My guess is no.

My gut says to try and insert the data in-order and then retrieving it becomes mapping the position in the canvas against the insert-order. However that's clumsy and inexact. The other option is to query the root data source and back into the calculation we used to get the position on the canvas in the first place. Also kind of clumsy, but at least we're removing the full iteration. Just curious if there's any tips or tricks to LINQ to replace the foreach but that doesn't actually do a foreach behind the scenes.

Comment: Inspiring by Video games and collision management: the space (your canvas) is devided in small pieces (rectangles). Each time you add a control to your canvas, you add it in the collection corresponding to the the rectangle containing its upper-left corner (easy to find). Then, you have to iterate only on the rectangles intersecting with you rectangle here...

Answer (score 1):

As @Kek alluded to, what you want is a hierarchical collision structure, like a QuadTree. I googled a bit and found what appears to be an ideal implementation (The QuadTree class is shamelessly lifted from [GaryTexmo's Generic QuadTree](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/insights/880968-generic-quadtree-implementation), the example code I threw together)

Sample output from this script:

```
Filling tree with 10000 rectangles took 00:00:00.0066186
1000 queries of quadtree took 00:00:00.4597303 and avged 4334 hits per query
```

Code:

```
void Main()
{
    var width = 10000;
    var height = 10000;
    var rectCount = 10000;
    var queryCount = 1000;
    var tree = new QuadTree<RectangleHolder>(0, 0, width, height);
    var rnd = new Random();
    var rects = Enumerable.Range(0, rectCount)
        .Select(_ => new { px = new []{rnd.Next(width), rnd.Next(width)}, py = new []{rnd.Next(height), rnd.Next(height)}})
        .Select(pts => new Rectangle(pts.px.Min(), pts.py.Min(), pts.px.Max() - pts.px.Min(), pts.py.Max() - pts.py.Min()))
        .ToList();
    var queryRanges = Enumerable.Range(0, queryCount)
        .Select(_ => new { px = new []{rnd.Next(width), rnd.Next(width)}, py = new []{rnd.Next(height), rnd.Next(height)}})
        .Select(pts => new Rectangle(pts.px.Min(), pts.py.Min(), pts.px.Max() - pts.px.Min(), pts.py.Max() - pts.py.Min()))
        .ToList();
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    foreach (var rect in rects)
    {
        tree.Insert(new RectangleHolder(rect));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Filling tree with {0} rectangles took {1}", rectCount, sw.Elapsed);
    sw.Restart();
    var totHits = 0;
    var res = new List<RectangleHolder>();
    foreach (var queryRect in queryRanges)
    {
        res.Clear();
        tree.GetObjects(queryRect, ref res);
        totHits += res.Count;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} queries of quadtree took {1} and avged {2} hits per query", queryCount, sw.Elapsed, (totHits / queryCount));
}

public class RectangleHolder : IHasRectangle
{
    public RectangleHolder(Rectangle rect)
    {
        Rect = rect;
    }

    public Rectangle Rect {get; private set;}
}

public interface IHasRectangle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The rectangle that defines the object's boundaries.
    /// </summary>
    Rectangle Rect { get; }
}

public class QuadTree<T> where T : IHasRectangle
{
    #region Constants
    // How many objects can exist in a QuadTree before it sub divides itself
    private const int MAX_OBJECTS_PER_NODE = 2;
    #endregion

    #region Private Members
    private List<T> m_objects = null;       // The objects in this QuadTree
    private Rectangle m_rect;               // The area this QuadTree represents

    private QuadTree<T> m_childTL = null;   // Top Left Child
    private QuadTree<T> m_childTR = null;   // Top Right Child
    private QuadTree<T> m_childBL = null;   // Bottom Left Child
    private QuadTree<T> m_childBR = null;   // Bottom Right Child
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// The area this QuadTree represents.
    /// </summary>
    public Rectangle QuadRect { get { return m_rect; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// The top left child for this QuadTree
    /// </summary>
    public QuadTree<T> TopLeftChild { get { return m_childTL; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// The top right child for this QuadTree
    /// </summary>
    public QuadTree<T> TopRightChild { get { return m_childTR; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// The bottom left child for this QuadTree
    /// </summary>
    public QuadTree<T> BottomLeftChild { get { return m_childBL; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// The bottom right child for this QuadTree
    /// </summary>
    public QuadTree<T> BottomRightChild { get { return m_childBR; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// The objects contained in this QuadTree at it's level (ie, excludes children)
    /// </summary>
    public List<T> Objects { get { return m_objects; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// How many total objects are contained within this QuadTree (ie, includes children)
    /// </summary>
    public int Count { get { return this.ObjectCount(); } }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a QuadTree for the specified area.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rect">The area this QuadTree object will encompass.</param>
    public QuadTree(Rectangle rect)
    {
        m_rect = rect;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a QuadTree for the specified area.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">The top-left position of the area rectangle.</param>
    /// <param name="y">The top-right position of the area reactangle.</param>
    /// <param name="width">The width of the area rectangle.</param>
    /// <param name="height">The height of the area rectangle.</param>
    public QuadTree(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        m_rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Add an item to the object list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to add.</param>
    private void Add(T item)
    {
        if (m_objects == null)
            m_objects = new List<T>();

        m_objects.Add(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove an item from the object list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The object to remove.</param>
    private void Remove(T item)
    {
        if (m_objects != null && m_objects.Contains(item))
            m_objects.Remove(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the total for all objects in this QuadTree, including children.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The number of objects contained within this QuadTree and its children.</returns>
    private int ObjectCount()
    {
        int count = 0;

        // Add the objects at this level
        if (m_objects != null) count += m_objects.Count;

        // Add the objects that are contained in the children
        if (m_childTL != null)
        {
            count += m_childTL.ObjectCount();
            count += m_childTR.ObjectCount();
            count += m_childBL.ObjectCount();
            count += m_childBR.ObjectCount();
        }

        return count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Subdivide this QuadTree and move it's children into the appropriate Quads where applicable.
    /// </summary>
    private void Subdivide()
    {
        // We've reached capacity, subdivide...
        Point size = new Point(m_rect.Width / 2, m_rect.Height / 2);
        Point mid = new Point(m_rect.X + size.X, m_rect.Y + size.Y);

        m_childTL = new QuadTree<T>(new Rectangle(m_rect.Left, m_rect.Top, size.X, size.Y));
        m_childTR = new QuadTree<T>(new Rectangle(mid.X, m_rect.Top, size.X, size.Y));
        m_childBL = new QuadTree<T>(new Rectangle(m_rect.Left, mid.Y, size.X, size.Y));
        m_childBR = new QuadTree<T>(new Rectangle(mid.X, mid.Y, size.X, size.Y));

        // If they're completely contained by the quad, bump objects down
        for (int i = 0; i < m_objects.Count; i++)
        {
            QuadTree<T> destTree = GetDestinationTree(m_objects[i]);

            if (destTree != this)
            {
                // Insert to the appropriate tree, remove the object, and back up one in the loop
                destTree.Insert(m_objects[i]);
                Remove(m_objects[i]);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the child Quad that would contain an object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The object to get a child for.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private QuadTree<T> GetDestinationTree(T item)
    {
        // If a child can't contain an object, it will live in this Quad
        QuadTree<T> destTree = this;

        if (m_childTL.QuadRect.Contains(item.Rect))
        {
            destTree = m_childTL;
        }
        else if (m_childTR.QuadRect.Contains(item.Rect))
        {
            destTree = m_childTR;
        }
        else if (m_childBL.QuadRect.Contains(item.Rect))
        {
            destTree = m_childBL;
        }
        else if (m_childBR.QuadRect.Contains(item.Rect))
        {
            destTree = m_childBR;
        }

        return destTree;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the QuadTree of all objects, including any objects living in its children.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        // Clear out the children, if we have any
        if (m_childTL != null)
        {
            m_childTL.Clear();
            m_childTR.Clear();
            m_childBL.Clear();
            m_childBR.Clear();
        }

        // Clear any objects at this level
        if (m_objects != null)
        {
            m_objects.Clear();
            m_objects = null;
        }

        // Set the children to null
        m_childTL = null;
        m_childTR = null;
        m_childBL = null;
        m_childBR = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes an item from this QuadTree. If the object is removed causes this Quad to have no objects in its children, it's children will be removed as well.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to remove.</param>
    public void Delete(T item)
    {
        // If this level contains the object, remove it
        bool objectRemoved = false;
        if (m_objects != null && m_objects.Contains(item))
        {
            Remove(item);
            objectRemoved = true;
        }

        // If we didn't find the object in this tree, try to delete from its children
        if (m_childTL != null && !objectRemoved)
        {
            m_childTL.Delete(item);
            m_childTR.Delete(item);
            m_childBL.Delete(item);
            m_childBR.Delete(item);
        }

        if (m_childTL != null)
        {
            // If all the children are empty, delete all the children
            if (m_childTL.Count == 0 &&
                m_childTR.Count == 0 &&
                m_childBL.Count == 0 &&
                m_childBR.Count == 0)
            {
                m_childTL = null;
                m_childTR = null;
                m_childBL = null;
                m_childBR = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert an item into this QuadTree object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to insert.</param>
    public void Insert(T item)
    {
        // If this quad doesn't intersect the items rectangle, do nothing
        if (!m_rect.Intersects(item.Rect))
            return;

        if (m_objects == null || 
            (m_childTL == null && m_objects.Count + 1 <= MAX_OBJECTS_PER_NODE))
        {
            // If there's room to add the object, just add it
            Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            // No quads, create them and bump objects down where appropriate
            if (m_childTL == null)
            {
                Subdivide();
            }

            // Find out which tree this object should go in and add it there
            QuadTree<T> destTree = GetDestinationTree(item);
            if (destTree == this)
            {
                Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                destTree.Insert(item);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the objects in this tree that intersect with the specified rectangle.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rect">The rectangle to find objects in.</param>
    /// <param name="results">A reference to a list that will be populated with the results.</param>
    public void GetObjects(Rectangle rect, ref List<T> results)
    {
        // We can't do anything if the results list doesn't exist
        if (results != null)
        {
            if (rect.Contains(m_rect))
            {
                // If the search area completely contains this quad, just get every object this quad and all it's children have
                GetAllObjects(ref results);
            }
            else if (rect.Intersects(m_rect))
            {
                // Otherwise, if the quad isn't fully contained, only add objects that intersect with the search rectangle
                if (m_objects != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < m_objects.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (rect.Intersects(m_objects[i].Rect))
                        {
                            results.Add(m_objects[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Get the objects for the search rectangle from the children
                if (m_childTL != null)
                {
                    m_childTL.GetObjects(rect, ref results);
                    m_childTR.GetObjects(rect, ref results);
                    m_childBL.GetObjects(rect, ref results);
                    m_childBR.GetObjects(rect, ref results);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all objects in this Quad, and it's children.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="results">A reference to a list in which to store the objects.</param>
    public void GetAllObjects(ref List<T> results)
    {
        // If this Quad has objects, add them
        if (m_objects != null)
            results.AddRange(m_objects);

        // If we have children, get their objects too
        if (m_childTL != null)
        {
            m_childTL.GetAllObjects(ref results);
            m_childTR.GetAllObjects(ref results);
            m_childBL.GetAllObjects(ref results);
            m_childBR.GetAllObjects(ref results);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static bool Intersects(this Rectangle lhs, Rectangle rhs)
    {
        var noIntersect =
            (lhs.Right < rhs.Left) ||
            (rhs.Right < lhs.Left) ||
            (lhs.Bottom < rhs.Top) ||
            (rhs.Bottom < lhs.Top);
        return !noIntersect;
    }
}
```